# PHP - Print array variable gives error

Tags: php

I'm trying this: `print "This is my car number $this->attr['number'] ... \n";`

But i get this error: `Array to string conversion ...`

How can i solve this syntax error and use `"` instead of `'`?

Comment: This is because `$this->attr['number']`is an array. Just `var_dump()` it and use the key for which you want the value to be printed.

Comment: @D4V1D you are wrong. PHP is evaluating `$this->attr` as the variable.

Comment: @rahultyagi read my last comment.

Comment: Err, no! Again, `$this->attr['number']` outputs an **array**, just as PHP just told you. You should access values of this array by doing `$this->attr['number']['key']`.

Comment: $this->attr is an array not this->attr['number']

Comment: What does `var_dump($this->attr);` outputs?

Comment: @D4V1D sorry but again, you are wrong. Please read the PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and Ctrl+F for "Complex (curly) syntax".

Comment: @Christopher: Right, didn't know about that. My bad :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print "This is my car number {$this->attr['number']} ... \n";
```

Putting variable in {} should solve your problem, because php evaluate it as one variable

Comment: Thanks! More info at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php (Complex (curly) syntax).